# Qlikview "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time""

Tags: server, connection, qlikview

I'm in QlikView. I have received the below error from the server.

> "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time or established connection.."

[image]

How can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this interface, but I guess you have to open port 4750 or at least enable HTTP tunneling at the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect via QlikView desktop or via the QlikView IE plug-in (i.e. Access Point) then you'll need to open port `4747`.

Reference: [Qlikview Server Reference Manual](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-8239). p 53